# Load column in csv file into spaCy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nltk, spacy

I am new to spaCy and NLTK as a whole, so I apologize in advance if this seems to be a dumb question.

Based on spaCy tutorial,I have to use the following command to load text into a doc.

```
doc = nlp(u'Hello, world. Natural Language Processing in 10 lines of code.')
```

However, I have a lot of text stored in tabular format on sql server or excel. It basically has two columns. First column has an unique identifier. Second column has a short text.

How do I load them into spaCy? Do I need to convert them into a Numpy array or Pandas dataframe and then load it into the doc?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Given a csv file like this:

```
$ cat test.tsv
DocID   Text    WhateverAnnotations
1   Foo bar bar dot dot dot
2   bar bar black sheep dot dot dot dot

$ cut -f2 test.tsv
Text
Foo bar bar
bar bar black sheep
```

And in code:

```
$ python
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv('test.tsv', delimiter='\t')
   DocID                 Text WhateverAnnotations
0      1          Foo bar bar         dot dot dot
1      2  bar bar black sheep     dot dot dot dot
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.tsv', delimiter='\t')
>>> df['Text']
0            Foo bar bar
1    bar bar black sheep
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

To use the `pipe` in spacy:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> for parsed_doc in nlp.pipe(iter(df['Text']), batch_size=1, n_threads=4):
...     print (parsed_doc[0].text, parsed_doc[0].tag_)
... 
Foo NNP
bar NN
```

To use `pandas.DataFrame.apply()`:

```
>>> df['Parsed'] = df['Text'].apply(nlp)

>>> df['Parsed'].iloc[0]
Foo bar bar
>>> type(df['Parsed'].iloc[0])
<class 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc'>
>>> df['Parsed'].iloc[0][0].tag_
'NNP'
>>> df['Parsed'].iloc[0][0].text
'Foo'
```

---

To benchmark.

First duplicate the rows 2 million times:

```
$ cat test.tsv 
DocID   Text    WhateverAnnotations
1   Foo bar bar dot dot dot
2   bar bar black sheep dot dot dot dot

$ tail -n 2 test.tsv > rows2

$ perl -ne 'print "$_" x1000000' rows2 > rows2000000

$ cat test.tsv rows2000000 > test-2M.tsv

$ wc -l test-2M.tsv 
 2000003 test-2M.tsv

$ head test-2M.tsv 
DocID   Text    WhateverAnnotations
1   Foo bar bar dot dot dot
2   bar bar black sheep dot dot dot dot
1   Foo bar bar dot dot dot
1   Foo bar bar dot dot dot
1   Foo bar bar dot dot dot
1   Foo bar bar dot dot dot
1   Foo bar bar dot dot dot
1   Foo bar bar dot dot dot
1   Foo bar bar dot dot dot
```

[nlppipe.py]:

```
import time

import pandas as pd
import spacy


df = pd.read_csv('test-2M.tsv', delimiter='\t')
nlp = spacy.load('en')

start = time.time()
for parsed_doc in nlp.pipe(iter(df['Text']), batch_size=1000, n_threads=4):
    x = parsed_doc[0].tag_
print (time.time() - start)
```

[dfapply.py]:

```
import time

import pandas as pd
import spacy


df = pd.read_csv('test-2M.tsv', delimiter='\t')
nlp = spacy.load('en')

start = time.time()
df['Parsed'] = df['Text'].apply(nlp)

for doc in df['Parsed']:
    x = doc[0].tag_
print (time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Would be useful if you stated the timing for each one so that we can see how they compare to each other. Even if the actual time would differ from machines

Answer (score 1):

I think alexis's comment to use `pandas` `.apply()` is the best answer, this worked great for me:

```
import spacy 

df = pd.read_csv('doc filename.txt')
df['text_as_spacy_objects'] = df['text column name'].apply(nlp)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple – you can use any method you want to read your texts from your database (Pandas dataframe, a CSV reader etc.) and then iterate over them.

It ultimately depends on what you want to do and how you want to process your text – if you want to process each text individually, simply iterate over your data line by line:

```
for id, line in text:
    doc = nlp(line)
    # do something with each text
```

Alternatively, you can also join the texts into one string and process them as one document:

```
text = open('some_large_text_file.txt').read()
doc = nlp(text)
```

For a more advanced usage example, see [this code snippet of streaming input and output](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/lightning-tour#multi-threaded) using `pipe()`.

Comment: But if read into a dataframe, the rows can be fed into `nlp` using `df.apply()` or equivalent, rather than iterating.